# File uploads from Google Drive using Safari on iPhone result in 0 byte files

Tags: iphone, forms, file-upload

We have a form on our website where you can apply for jobs, and it has a file upload field so you can upload your resumé. It allows .doc, .docx and .pdf files.

Sometimes the form submits successfully but the file is 0 bytes on our server.

I was able to figure out that all the form submissions that result in a 0 byte file upload were from iPhones, and by filling out the form myself on my iPhone, discovered that if the resumé is stored on Google Drive, and then I upload it via the form, that's what results in the 0 byte file.

If it's stored on iCloud Drive, then it's fine. It's an appropriately sized file that opens properly in the right application (Acrobat or Word).

Anybody have any suggestions as to how I can remedy the situation, or where to even start? I have Googled it extensively, and can't find any other discussion of this particular weirdness. Apologies if this is the wrong place to post the question, and I would appreciate pointers to the right place if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is an iOS bug, still present in version 12.3.1 and dating back to at least 2016, we have the same issue. I think the only options that exist are: prevent the form being used on iOS, detect 0 byte files in server-side validation and ask the user to resubmit (not great but at least you're not losing data), or move to an AJAX-style file upload. See also [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011849/0-bytes-uploaded-of-file-stored-on-cloud-service-via-input-type-file-on-ios).