# 0 bytes uploaded of file stored on cloud service via <input type=file> on iOS

Tags: ios, file-upload, cloud

I'm having trouble working out why some uploads to our server from iOS result in empty files. The upload page is a simple form using POST and enctype as multipart/form-data.

The problem only seems to arise when the user:

1. Is using iOS
2. Attempts to upload a file from a cloud service (currently iCloud or Dropbox) **even if the file is the version on their local system**
3. Leaves a period of time between selecting the file (via a `<input type=file>` button) and initiating the upload, roughly about 30sec to 1min.

I'm not sure if there is a timeout issue with the connection to the file, and if so, whether this is a bug or a security feature. If the user selects their file and initiates the upload within this time, the file uploads successfully.

Uploads from the 'true' local system (eg. outside any cloud folders) upload fine, even after any delay. The file size and file type seem to be irrelevant.

I'm aware Dropbox have a 'Chooser' system, which forwards a link instead of the file, however in testing, a Dropbox file will still upload successfully provided the user does so within a short time.

The form that handles the upload is rather large with many options, so typically a user will spend some time between selecting the file and initiating the upload.

The problem does not occur on Android or OSX desktop platforms.

I have also tested using an independent online uploader, namely http://checkfiletype.com/ and performed the same test, and the same thing happens:

[result after pressing 'upload' straight away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP6IB.jpg), 
and 
[result after short a delay and then pressing 'upload'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tG3B.jpg)

I'm not sure where to go from here, most Googling only turns up results about uploading TO cloud platforms, instead of from them. Am I missing something?

Comment: did you find a solution for this

Comment: @Sudarshana Dayananda Unfortunately no. There has been an update to iOS since I first posted- but the issue still exists.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue using a popular form plugin for wordpress, can't understand why there is no trace of this around...

Comment: @BradfordLongflap You helped put an end to a few hours troubleshooting to narrow down this issue on our forms.. how did you end up solving it? Move to ajax uploading?

Comment: @ronnz I never solved it. Ajax isn't really practical for us in this case- as a compromise I have a note at the top of the form (triggered by iOS user agent) prompting users to move the image file(s) into their 'photos' folder before uploading.

Comment: @BradfordLongflap thanks for the info! Helped a lot debugging.

Comment: as a short term solution you can get a cloud file link from user and convert it to direct download link and save it to your server and add the address to database or memory.

Answer (score 1):

Update: This appears to be no longer be the case with the release of iOS 15.4. The [updates page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212788) contains under 'bug fixes':

> Photos and videos may not sync to iCloud Photo Library

Whilst it doesn't describe the bug directly, it appears the dev teams have actually made adjustments to the chooser/file system. What a shame it took several years.